# How do I match everything between first set of brackets?

Tags: php, regex

How do I parse everything between the first set of { } brackets via a PHP string. How would I  go about doing that?  The string contains multiple bracket sets but I only want to grab the first set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse the first segment using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343999/how-do-i-parse-the-first-segment-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try regular expression

```
$sample = "hello heooolloo {wooow} hiii hello ";
preg_match('/{(.*?)}/', $sample, $match);
echo $match[1]; //prints wooow
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex:

```
^[^{]*{([^}]*)
```

Explanation:

```
^       - string beginning
[^{]*   - any character except {
{       - desired {
([^}]*) - match every char except closing }
```